# Powerbi angular library error when installed

Tags: angular, powerbi-embedded

I'm using this library to include powerbi by using embed token, and embedurl. But when i install the dependencies and the library i'm getting error.

This is the library i'm using to load the powerbi https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-powerbi (ngx-powerbi)

I'm getting this error

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ngx-powerbi/node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi-client.d.ts(1477,13):
>   error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'powerbi' must be of type 'Ser vice', but here has
>   type 'Service'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting this error, please log a defect in the library GitHub's defect section and I will look into it